# How to handle 404 error for a Angular App deployed in jBoss Server?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

`{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }` -> in app.module.ts

`<base href="/">` -> in index.html

Using the above 2 ways I'm able to remove `#` from URL, but If I refresh the page I'm facing 404 error only when I build and deploy my application in jBoss server. In my local it's working fine even If I refresh the page.

Is there any way to handle this either from Angular side or from server side?

I have added below code in web.xml

`<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>`

But It is navigating to landing page. Can we make it stay in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know specifically about jBoss server but in order for angular router to take control of your app, index.html must be returned by server in case of 404 error. Did you check it ?

Comment: Can you check it with **HashLocationStrategy** ? This will clarify whether something is wrong in angular or server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `<base href="/your-app/">` in index.html and then context-root in **jboss-web.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/your-app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

You should be sure that all compiled angular files are in **webapp**

See you :)